# How to make non executable library (jar) using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am working on an application and deploying in cloud foundry. Internally it is having 3 custom dependencies developed by our team.

All 3 dependencies are boot project and have their `@Configuration`.

- Dependency 1 is to interact with Couchbase. Source of this dependency is boot project.
- Dependency 2 is to interact with FluentD for logging. Source of this dependency is boot project.
- Dependency 3 is to interact with external rest service. Source of this dependency is boot project.
- Dependency 4 is having all these above 3 dependencies and also having few utils classes and constants.

I am using this dependency 4 in multiple web applications which are having WebMVC implementation.

Everything is working fine in my local machine. But when I am pushing this web application on cloud, sometimes libraries getting executed before the web application which is crashing my app intermittently. Good thing app is getting recover in few seconds.

I did below changes in my libraries (jars/dependencies) and tried on cloud. After doing these changes ratio of app crash reduces, but unfortunately it is still crashing sometimes and I am able to see dependencies gets executed before application.

- Added bootRepackage.enabled = false bootRepackage.withJarTask = jar in library's build.gradle
- Took off from library and added in my web application
  springBoot {
  mainClass  = "com.java.Application"
  executable = true
  }
- Took off `@SpringBootApplication` from libraries(dependencies/jars). It's just in my web application now.

I do not know these are the only steps to make a boot dependency non-executable or I would have to do something else. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Here is the sample off application class of one of my dependency.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

  @ComponentScan
  public class LoggingApplication {

  }

Sample of Web application main class.
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableWebMvc
  @Import(LoggingApplication.class) 
  public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does "sometimes libraries getting executed before the web application" mean? Libraries aren't really supposed to execute anything.

Comment: And honestly, if they're internal dependencies not full-fledged applications then why the hell are you even using Spring Boot? The normal Spring Framework should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't expose stacktrace nor provided any specifics of "crash". So looking into my crystal ball, this sounds like you are doing some work during wiring phase of Spring IoC container. This "work" should be moved into `@PostConstruct` handlers, so that you are sure it will be executed after Spring Context is fully created and initialized.